# Reduce or Limit to have positive value!

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I would like to see where this function is positive ??!!

```
  Reduce[{Tanh[x]/Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x]^2] > 0}, x, Reals]
```

thank you.

Comment: Alternate form assuming x is real     -i sinh(x)

Comment: `FindInstance[Tanh[x]/Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x]^2] == 1/100, x, Complexes, 30]` produces 30 solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The result of the command

```
Reduce[Tanh[x]/Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x]^2] > 0, x, Reals]
```

> `False`

says there is no real solution. The solutions over the complexes can be described in such a way.

```
Reduce[Tanh[x]/Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x]^2]==a && a > 0, x, Complexes]
```

> `C[1] \[Element]  Integers && ((0 < a < 1 &&  x == I ArcTan[Sqrt[-(a^2/(-1 + a^2))]] + I \[Pi] C[1]) || (a >  1 && x == ArcTanh[Sqrt[a^2/(-1 + a^2)]] + I \[Pi] C[1]))`

Comment: `Reduce[Tanh[x]/Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x]^2]> 0, x, Complexes]` fails.